# Is the user's marker inside one or mutliple polygons loaded from a KML file?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, polygon, kml

My client gave me a kml file containing multiple polygons. Each representing an area and a degree of risk of being flooded.
He wants a user to come to his website, search for his/her address, and see if he is at risk of being flooded.

Since the KML file is pretty big, I am trying first to do it on a single town: I displayed a Google map and have no problems displaying a marker on it.

How can I now load a KML file on that same map, and compare whether the marker is included in one of the areas ?

I am a beginner at programming and this is a bit of a personal challenge, so in advance, thanks for your help!

-J

Comment: something like [this example](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_collection-map2e.html)?

Comment: Yes, that looks very promessing! How did you import the zones? If it's from a Kml file, you're the man :)

Comment: From a KML file.

Answer (score -1):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Polygon.html

There's probably a translation of this for javascript.

Comment: There is a contains method in the polygon class.